# Could not find configuration file provided by "opencv_calib3d" when building ros1_bridge

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04
DDS Implementation CycloneDDS.

Hi there. I have tried building ros1_bridge based on the instructions but I am facing an issue (see issue below) after executing
`colcon build --packages-select ros1_bridge --cmake-force-configure`

```
Starting >>> ros1_bridge
--- stderr: ros1_bridge                         
CMake Error at /opt/ros/foxy/share/theora_image_transport/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:21 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findopencv_calib3d.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "opencv_calib3d", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "opencv_calib3d"

 with any of the following names:

    opencv_calib3dConfig.cmake
    opencv_calib3d-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "opencv_calib3d" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "opencv_calib3d_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "opencv_calib3d" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/foxy/share/theora_image_transport/cmake/theora_image_transportConfig.cmake:41 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:97 (find_package)


---
Failed   <<< ros1_bridge [2.92s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 0 packages finished [3.05s]
  1 package failed: ros1_bridge
  1 package had stderr output: ros1_bridge
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374303/could-not-find-configuration-file-provided-by-%22opencv_calib3d%22-when-building-ros1_bridge/) by [rosuser](https://answers.ros.org/users/72165/rosuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-03-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [**spam**](https://answers.ros.org/users/73548/__spam__/) on 2021-05-26**:
Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answered on github:
https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge/issues/276#issuecomment-659441483

---

Originally posted by [vrichard](https://answers.ros.org/users/36745/vrichard/) with karma: 108 on 2021-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0